# Expo: How to persist data across multiple installations of the app

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo, android-keystore

Is there a way to persist data across multiple reinstallations of the app other than using Expo SecureStore. 
I need the unique identifier of the app (UUID) to persist across multiple installations. 
I was using Expo Secure Store, but there seems to be a problem with Expo not being able to access the Securestore in Android version 8.1. I get this error:  [Error: Could not decrypt the item in SecureStore] (This seems to be specific to Android version 8.1).
I tried writing it into the FileSystem but it seems to get wiped out when the app uninstalls.
Are there any other options?